# Is there a method in Windows to have a popup box with text, images and company branding?

Tags: windows-10

I've been tasked with a job where we need domain users to have a Popup Box appear with a Health and Safety message of the day either when they login or just after.

I found I can do this within Local Security Policy, but it only allows text, no images.

Is there anyway or any software that would allow me to achieve this?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What stops you from writing a small program, that displays it (e.g. a WebView) and deploy this as part of the login script via GP ?

Comment: Nothing stops me from doing so, but I would need some help with it that's for sure.

Whereabouts in GP would it be to deploy this? - don't worry found the GP Location